# Where is my input current value stored?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's consider this code:

```html
<input type="text" id="my-input" value="foo">
```

If I change the text inside the input box, I know I can retrieve it via:

- `$('#my-input').val()`
- `document.getElementById('my-input').value`

But if I <kbd>Right click</kbd> > <kbd>Inspect</kbd> I will see something like:

[image]

Is there any way to **see** the value `foobar` inside the DOM? If not, where is this value stored?

This question is browser agnostic, the background that lead be here is a weird bug in `IE 11.0.14`

Comment: @AlvaroGonzalez what's that edit? I'm using FF?!

Comment: My excuses, you omitted that information and I had the impression that screen-shot belong to Chrome. Also, Chrome users never care mentioning the browser ;-) -- Could you please re-tag yourself, or at least explain what browsers you need to cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to see it inside the DOM?

Not in most of the DOM inspectors in browsers today (apparently you can see something showing its value, as an implementation detail, in Chrome by viewing the shadow DOM; see [Andrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42980340/157247)). It doesn't correspond to any attribute, for instance, and those DOM inspectors tend to show the current element and attributes, but not other properties. They certainly *could*, I've just never seen one that did.

> If not, where is this value stored?

In a property on the element. Elements are objects, of course, within the DOM implementation of the browser. `HTMLInputElement` has a [`value` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value), and that's where the current value is stored. There's no HTML attribute defined for that; the [`value` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) is the **default** value of the `input`, not its current value. (It's reflected in the [`defaultValue` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-defaultvalue).) So unlike, say, the `id` property, which directly reflects the `id` attribute, `value` is not a reflected property at all (because there's no corresponding attribute for it to reflect).

Answer (score 14):

I can say for Chrome. To see input value in DOM you need to enable `Show user agent shadow DOM` in developer tools settings > Elements.

So you will be able to see `#inner-editor` with input value in it.
[image: Screenshot]

### Addition for Firefox

You can reveal input value in via developer tools with following steps:

1. Find your input in DOM
2. Right click on it and select `Shadow DOM properties`
3. You'll see properties at the bottom-right part of the tools.
   [image]

**Note**: this is not the same as in Chrome, it's similar to revealing value using javascript.

Comment: Is this option available in FF ?

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if that's reliable release-on-release, or an implementation detail that's open to change, that gets exposed by looking at the shadow DOM.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub don't think as it's [still in working draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM), looks like Chrome as of version 53 and Safari as of version 10 do support it

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option like this in FF. Also, we need to understand that this is just a debugging tool, so it doesn't need to be in standard, and doesn't need to be implemented in every browser. And it could be changed in different releases.

Comment: I've added the way for firefox, that will allow finding actual input value. Maybe someone will find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An input (and most types of HTML elements) have a whole bunch of properties that are not explicitly part of the HTML tree. As you have found, updating an input does not modify its HTML. The value is stored internally.

Some browsers' debugging tools (such as those in Chrome) provide a Properties tab that you can use to view a selected element's properties. If you view the `value` property there, it will show you the element's current value.

In the Firefox debugging tools, you can right-click the element in the DOM viewer and select "Use in console". This will drop a temp variable into the console that you can use to access the element's properties (including its `.value`).